# How determine when last time USB hard/flash drive was read/written to?

Tags: disk-image, file-attributes

I am trying to determine when a file was last written to a USB hard/flash drive. An image was restored to a USB hard drive using [this USB image tool](http://www.alexpage.de/usb-image-tool/download/).

The modification/creation dates are old since the image was created some time ago. Is there any way to determine when the image was restored (written) to the USB hard drive?